# Not able to set the frame of the xib view to resize

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I am trying to create a view using xib and dynamically presenting in the viewController. I am passing the frame parameters while setting up the view :

```
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 171, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height - 327)
        self.xibView = xibView(frame: frame)
        self.view.addSubview(self.xibView)
        self.xibView.delegate = self
```

in the Xib view My structure looks like this :

[image]

I have added stackView so that the content resizes automatically based on frame size that we provide. On the code, we are doing :

```
class xibView: UIView {

    // some other declarations

    @IBOutlet weak var sharpBtn: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
    
    public var delegate: xibViewDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit(){
        // write view stuff here
        
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("xibView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Here contentView is the view below safe area that we have in the hierarchy.

When I am trying to run it, The descriptor for the view gives me :

```
<UIView: 0x7fd5c54077a0; frame = (0 0; 835 867); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001708500>>
```

This is the size of freeform xib that I have created. I am not sure if there is something that I am missing to make the view resize to the frame that we provide.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

For the update I was able to fix the following issue by assigning the frame to the view in layoutSubviews function.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // we need to adjust the frame of the subview to no longer match the size used
        // in the XIB file BUT the actual frame we got assinged from the superview
        self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    }
```

and then setting the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true in the init function :

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```